# how to undelete a file in a solution in Visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I added a class file to the solution.

Then after sometime I accidently deleted the class file.
Is there any option to undelete the deleted class file??

Note: I was not working in TFS

Apart from manually copying from recycle bin is there an option to restore it?

something like a `ctrl+z` ?

Comment: Which VS? Did you delete it or remove it? Why aren't you using version control?

Comment: Visual studio 2012, No i was not having the solution in TFS

Comment: What would you do if you've accidently deleted a word-document on your computer?

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter it didnt strike me to chk in recycle bin for it!! i was pissed off after i wrongly deleted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your Recycle Bin. It is most probably there. You will then have to manually include it in your project.